# Sort ArrayList of Object by a String parameter inside the Object

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an object `Product` that has the follow parameters:

```
String name;
int quantity;
String date;
```

where `date` is the toString of a `GregorianCalendar` object;

If I have an `ArrayList<Product>` myList, I want to return a new ArrayList of `Product` object sorted by `date` cronologically not alfabetically(I have already a method to convert String in GregorianCalendar but I don't know how use this in the compareTo method for sorting).

Since the list is not a simple `ArrayList<String>` and the sorting depends by an internal parameter in the `ArrayList` of object, how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it would be better to store date as a `GregorianCalendar` object and not as `String`.

Then just create a custom comparator and compare only the date field using its `compareTo` method (inherited from the `Calendar` class).

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Product>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Product p0, Product p1) {
           return p0.getDate().compareTo(p1.getDate());
       }
});
```

Comment: I know, however I have a methopd to convert the GregorianCalendar and viceversa. how could I use this to sort cronologically using comparator?

Comment: @AndreaF You can call this method first to transform your String as a date object and then call compareTo, however it seems more suitable to store a date as a date and just give its String representation when you want to display it.

Comment: unfortunately the object stored have date as String and change this will cause problems in many method of the project

Comment: @AndreaF Then use this method in the compare method to convert the String as Date first for both and then call compareTo. Something like `return myMethod(p0.getDate()).compareTo(myMethod(p1.getDate()));`

Comment: but I don't have understand where exactly I have to place your piece of code

Comment: @AndreaF What piece? `Collections.sort`? If yes, call this when you want to sort your list, so in a place where you need to use your list after you sorted it.

Comment: Ah OK now is clear ...but if I want to sort the collection by another parameter in future?

Comment: @AndreaF let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48609/discussion-between-zouzou-and-andreaf)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Comparator` to sort the array list of Product class

Comment: Could you give me more details?

Comment: The problem is the cronological order. I have a methopd to convert the GregorianCalendar to String and viceversa. how could I use this to sort cronologically using comparator (otherwise will be sorted alfabetically by date)?

Comment: If u want to convert Date into String and vice versa, you can go with SimpleDateFormat class

Comment: I yet have a method to convert String in `GregorianCalendar` but i don't know how shoud I use this in the compareTo

Comment: A `GregorianCalendar` already implements `Comparable<Calendar>` so you can just call the `compareTo` method of the calendar object to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

if you add implements Comparable  to your Product class declaration and 
add something like the following method

```
/**
 * Compares this object with the specified object for order.  Returns a
 * negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
 * than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
 * <p/>
 * <p>The implementor must ensure <tt>sgn(x.compareTo(y)) ==
 * -sgn(y.compareTo(x))</tt> for all <tt>x</tt> and <tt>y</tt>.  (This
 * implies that <tt>x.compareTo(y)</tt> must throw an exception iff
 * <tt>y.compareTo(x)</tt> throws an exception.)
 * <p/>
 * <p>The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
 * <tt>(x.compareTo(y)&gt;0 &amp;&amp; y.compareTo(z)&gt;0)</tt> implies
 * <tt>x.compareTo(z)&gt;0</tt>.
 * <p/>
 * <p>Finally, the implementor must ensure that <tt>x.compareTo(y)==0</tt>
 * implies that <tt>sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))</tt>, for
 * all <tt>z</tt>.
 * <p/>
 * <p>It is strongly recommended, but <i>not</i> strictly required that
 * <tt>(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))</tt>.  Generally speaking, any
 * class that implements the <tt>Comparable</tt> interface and violates
 * this condition should clearly indicate this fact.  The recommended
 * language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is
 * inconsistent with equals."
 * <p/>
 * <p>In the foregoing description, the notation
 * <tt>sgn(</tt><i>expression</i><tt>)</tt> designates the mathematical
 * <i>signum</i> function, which is defined to return one of <tt>-1</tt>,
 * <tt>0</tt>, or <tt>1</tt> according to whether the value of
 * <i>expression</i> is negative, zero or positive.
 *
 * @param o the object to be compared.
 * @return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object
 *         is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified object is null
 * @throws ClassCastException   if the specified object's type prevents it
 *                              from being compared to this object.
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Product o) {
 // add logic to compare this products date with the other's (o.getDate())
// return 1 if this products date is greater than the other's  and 
// return -1 if this product's date is less than the other's

   return 0; if they are the same.  
}
```

This will determine the default sort order for Collections of Products.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Date as `GregorianCalendar` or `java.util.Date` and Implement Comparable Interface in the Product class. So you need to override the method called `compareTo(Product p)`.

```
public class  Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    String name;
    int quantity;
    Date date;

    @override
    public int compareTo(Product p1){
      return this.date.compareTo(p1.date); //line 9 for ascending order 
    }
}
```

Use `Collection.sort(list)`; whereever you need to sort the list of products based on date. For descending order, replace line 9 with `return p1.date.compareTo(this.date);`.

Comment: make it as Comparable<Product>.